# iMacros: EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND on !URLCURRENT

Tags: imacros

Is it possible to make `EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND` work on `{{!URLCURRENT}}`?

E.g, if i visit a site, and submit something, sometimes when things goes wrong, I get redirected to a error page, for example `sample.com/submit?sorry-information-already-in-the-database-239929.html`

So, I would want to generate error -990 if "sorry" is found in the current url.

This obviously don't' work:

```
TAG {{!URLCURRENT}} ATTR=HREF:sorry CONTENT=EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EVAL` to emit exception:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("/sorry/.test('{{!URLCURRENT}}') && MacroError('wrong page')")
```

Comment: I didn't know that iMacros by default stops with http status code 404 or 503, I removed SET !ERRORIGNORE YES and this solved it for me. But if I face a situation where I get back status code 200 on a "wrong" page, I will use your solution, thanks!